# What is the best way to implement the python count function in java?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I am learning how to use streams in java and I would like to know the most efficient way to copy the python count functionality into java.

For those unfamiliar with python count, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm).

I've already done a naive implementation but I doubt this would ever get added to a production level environment:

```
private List<String> countMessages(List<String> messages) {
        Map<String, Integer> messageOccurrences = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> stackedMessages = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.messages.stream().filter((message) -> (messageOccurrences.containsKey(message))).forEachOrdered((message) -> {
                    int new_occ = messageOccurrences.get(message) + 1;
                    messageOccurrences.put(message, new_occ);
        });
        messageOccurrences.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
            stackedMessages.add(key + "(" + messageOccurrences.get(key) + "times)" );
        });
        return stackedMessages;
    }
```

Any improvements or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that looks a complicated way to do what pythons list `count()` method does. do you not just want `long count = this.messages.stream().filter((message) -> message.equals(messages)).count();` ? if not then please elaborate...

Comment: @Aominè I had made a mistake when I first submitted the question. The function should take the list of messages and return a hashmap with the message as the key and the number of times it appeared in the list as the value. I must do this using streams.

Comment: As a stylistic note, your code becomes more readable if you don’t pollute it with so many braces. Instead of `(name) -> (expression)`, just write `name -> expression`. Further, instead of `(name) -> { singleMethodInvocation(); }`, just write `name -> singleMethodInvocation()`. Then, don’t iterate over a `keySet()` to perform a `get()` on the map for each key, as that’s not only visual noise, it’s inefficient. You can iterate over the `entrySet()` or here, just use `messageOccurrences.forEach((key, value) -> stackedMessages.add(key + "(" + value + "times)" )`…

Comment: And consider [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488) (spoiler: almost never).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question "what is the best way to implement the python count function in java?".

Java already has [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) which will do exactly that.

However, if you want to do it with the streams API then I believe a generic solution would be:

```
public static <T> long count(Collection<T> source, T element) {
       return source.stream().filter(e -> Objects.equals(e, element)).count();
}
```

then the use case would be:

```
long countHellp = count(myStringList, "hello");
long countJohn = count(peopleList, new Person("John"));
long count101 = count(integerList, 101); 
...
...
```

or you can even pass a predicate if you wanted:

```
public static <T> long count(Collection<T> source, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
       return source.stream().filter(predicate).count();
}
```

Then the use case would be for example:

```
long stringsGreaterThanTen = count(myStringList, s -> s.length() > 10);
long malesCount = count(peopleList, Person::isMale);
long evens = count(integerList, i -> i % 2 == 0); 
...
...
```

---

Given your comment on the post, it seems like you want to "group" then and get the count of each group.

```
public Map<String, Long> countMessages(List<String> messages) {
        return messages.stream()
                       .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
}
```

This creates a stream from the `messages` list and then groups them, passing a `counting()` as the downstream collector meaning we will retrieve a `Map<String, Long>` where the keys are the elements and the values are the occurrences of that specific string.

Ensure you have the import:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

for the latter solution.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is there a way to cast the `Long` return value to an `Integer` within the function? Also marking this as the answer because it got me my desired result

Comment: @Q.H. it's not a stupid question at all. that's a good question. simply change `counting()` to `summingInt(e -> 1)` .

Comment: Don’t use `e -> Objects.equals(e, element)`, use `Predicate.isEqual(element)`. Besides having less noise, it’s implemented equivalent to `element == null? Object::isNull: element::equals`, which doesn’t repeat the `null` check for every stream element.

Comment: @Holger Right, thanks. will keep that in mind from now on.